# How to reshape a tensor with multiple `None` dimensions?

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, tensor

I encountered a problem to reshape an intermediate 4D tensorflow tensor `X` to a 3D tensor `Y`, where

- `X` is of shape `( batch_size, nb_rows, nb_cols, nb_filters )`
- `Y` is of shape `( batch_size, nb_rows*nb_cols, nb_filters )`
- `batch_size = None`

Of course, when `nb_rows` and `nb_cols` are known integers, I can reshape `X` without any problem. However, in my application I need to deal with the case

`nb_rows = nb_cols = None`

What should I do? I tried `Y = tf.reshape( X, (-1, -1, nb_filters))` but it clearly fails to work.

For me, this operation is deterministic because it always squeezes the two middle axes into a single one while keeping the first axis and the last axis unchanged. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can access to the dynamic shape of `X` through `tf.shape(X)`:

```
shape = [tf.shape(X)[k] for k in range(4)]
Y = tf.reshape(X, [shape[0], shape[1]*shape[2], shape[3]])
```

Comment: Trying to do this gives me TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

Comment: Change the first line to `shape = [ tf.shape(X)[k] for k in range(4)]`.

Comment: If I have a tensor of shape (None, 100,80) and i want to reshape it to (100, None*80) , the resulting tensor is having shape (?,?). why

Comment: @SandeepPandey I guess you should try first to transpose it and then to reshape it. 
`X = tf.transpose(X, [1, 0, 2])`
`shape = [ tf.shape(X)[k] for k in range(3)]`
`X = tf.reshape(X, [shape[0], shape[1]*shape[2])`