# Tensorflow Reshape fails with TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a tensor representing an embedding and I want to reshape it but it fails with the following error:

> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use
>   `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined,
>   and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs
>   conditioned on the value of a tensor.

The code that I use for reshaping:

```
embedding_feature = \
    Reshape((tf.shape(embedding_feature)[0],
             10, 20, tf.shape(embedding_feature)[2])) \
        (embedding_feature)
```

and the embedding_feature:

```
Tensor("tags_embedding/GatherV2:0", shape=(?, 200, 60), dtype=float32)
```

I am using `tf.shape()` to capture the dynamic shape of the tensor as explained in other questions here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7253

[How to reshape a tensor with multiple `None` dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026042/how-to-reshape-a-tensor-with-multiple-none-dimensions)

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/eleni/Desktop/recommender/recommender/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5285, in get_controller
    yield g
  File "/home/eleni/Desktop/recommender/recommender/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 622, in __call__
    output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
  File "/home/eleni/Desktop/recommender/recommender/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 390, in compute_output_shape
    input_shape[1:], self.target_shape)
  File "/home/eleni/Desktop/recommender/recommender/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 364, in _fix_unknown_dimension
    if dim < 0:
  File "/home/eleni/Desktop/recommender/recommender/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 665, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: It's not clear when/where the error is happening at a glance. Could you add full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Reshape`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer requires a tuple of integers as input (also, the dimensions given to the layer should not include the batch dimension). If you want to reshape to a shape not known in advance, use a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K

# ...
embedding_feature = Lambda(
     lambda x: K.reshape(x, [K.shape(x)[0], 10, 20, K.shape(x)[2]]))(embedding_feature)
```